# why I can't use the password to login mysql server by using the docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

Here is the shell, I'm trying to run in this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cur_dir=`pwd`
docker stop mysql
docker rm mysql
docker run --name mysql \ 
-v ${cur_dir}/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d \ 
-v ${cur_dir}/data:/var/lib/mysql \
-p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql:latest
```

And the version of mysql is 8.0, Here is the env inside the Docker container:

```
HOSTNAME=b36067a0e291
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
PWD=/
HOME=/root
MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
GOSU_VERSION=1.7
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.13-1debian9
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=1
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
_=/usr/bin/env
```

And Here is file my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8mb4
[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
```

I've already set the host '%'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most probably you need to set `allowPublicKeyRetrieval` to `true` on the client

Comment: assuming you have mysql client installed check the following works docker run --name mysql -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -d mysql:latest  and then mysql --get-server-public-key=TRUE --port=3306 --user=root --host=127.0.0.1 --password=123456 -v